# How to use a continuous query when down sampling in InfluxDB/InfluxQL

Tags: time-series, influxdb

I have a table/serie like this

```
Message              MessageValue 
 ---------------      ---------------------   
property1                         10            
property2                         9
property3                         7
property2                         22
```

I want to downsample property2's mean value every 10 minutes. How would I do something like this?

CREATE CONTINUOUS QUERY "cq_10m" ON "DatabaseName" BEGIN SELECT mean(SELECT MessageValue WHERE Message =property2 ) AS "mean_Property2" INTO "RetentionPolicyName"."downsampled_orders" FROM "TableName" GROUP BY time(10m) END

Answer (score 0):

It would look something like below. Your CQ will query the db every 10 minutes and will calculate the mean of "MessageValue" across that time frame. This will be downsampled into: mean_Property2.

```
CREATE CONTINUOUS QUERY "cq_10m" ON "dbName"
RESAMPLE EVERY 10m FOR 2h
BEGIN SELECT mean("MessageValue") AS mean_Property2 INTO 
mean_Property2 FROM "retentionPolicyName"."measurementName" WHERE "Message"='property2'
GROUP BY time(10m) END
```